# Why is the shape of 299 pixels x 299 pixels RGB image model 299 x 299 x 3 rather than 1 x 1 x 3? I am using Tensorflow in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am reading this Python tutorial about binary image classification using Tensorflow.

The tutorial is here:
https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/skin-cancer-detection-using-tensorflow-in-python

Most of it makes sense to me.
However I am confused about the shape of the model.

The article says `600 images of the shape (299, 299, 3) can fit our memory, let's convert our test set from tf.data into a NumPy array`.

I do not understand why the shape of the model is `299, 299, 3`.
Shouldn't the shape be `1, 1 ,3`?

I am not talking about images with only a single pixel.
For images of `299 x 299` pixels and 3 color depth, the dimension of the model should be `1 x 1 x 3` rather than `299 x 299 x 3` .

This line here supposedly creates a model of 4 dimensions:  Anything x 299 x 299 x 3.

```
m.build([None, 299, 299, 3])
```

The "3" refers to the three channels (R, G, and B).
Each of the R, G, and B can contain a value of 0 - 255.
R can be 0 - 255,
G can be 0 - 255,
B can be 0 - 255.

To find the red value at coordinate 135,246, this will do the job:

```
red_value = img[135, 246, 0]
```

X and Y pixel coordinate values can be 1 - 299.
The 135 refers to X coordinate , and the 246 is Y coordinate of a pixel.  RBG are stored in [ ,,0], [,,1] and [,,2].

My question is this: Shouldn't the dimension of the model be just 1 x 1 x 3 ?  rather than 299 x 299 x 3 ?  because X coordinate is one variable, and Y coordinate is one variable.  RBG are three variables.  1 x 1 x 3

For the RBG channels, you don't need a model of 299 x 299 x "255" or a model of 299 x 299 x 255 x 255 x 255.   Just 299 x 299 x "3" will do the job.
So why is that for pixel coordinate of 1 - 299, we need to use "299" x "299" x 255? rather than just "1" x "1" x 3?

The shape of the model should be something like :  `(int x, int y, int[R][G][B])`  which is a 1 x 1 x 3 .

Am I right? or is my concept erroneous somewhere?  Please correct me.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Each image has 299x299x3 values. These values range from 0-255. Think of it as a 3d volume. There's nothing special about that 3rd dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the ML jargon can be confusing.

Images are *rank-3 tensors*, they have 3 axis: height, width, and channels (or depth). To train the model is usually added a fourth axis representing the batch size, so you end up with rank-4 tensors.

Now, when you define the input shape of some layer or model you have to think about the rank (or num. axis) you input data has: images have 3 so the tuple has 3 elements, like `(A, B, C)`. Note: This tuple does not indicate the dimensionality of the data, in a strict mathematical sense. To get that you have to multiply each value of the shape tuple, i.e. `dim = A x B x C`.

So, what values to assign to `A`, `B`, and `C`? Each of these represent the dimensionality of the single axis. For images: `A` is the dimensionality related to the *height axis* (i.e. first dimension) that is the num. of rows the image have (`299` in this case); `B` accounts for the *width axis* (i.e. second dimension of the image tensor) so `B=299` i.e. the num. of columns; lastly, `C` is the dim. of the third channel axis: `C=3`.

To sum up: the input shape `(A,B,C)` should be `(299,299,3)` that indicates a rank-3 tensor of dimensionality `299 X 299 X 3 = 268262` (the dimensionality of each image is just the total number of pixels they have.)